# How to get access from another store in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, customer

Still i have been maintaining a **single store on world wide** in Magento.Now I have created an **new store for UK folks**. Hereafter they will redirected to UK store, when they open Main store.

Still here, All are working good. But My doubt is, **already being customer can access their account from UK store?** If change the store Id of the customer, Its possible, I think. But Its too hard to find who is UK customers. Is there any possible way to access their account from another store?

Please Help me guys. Awaiting for your suggestion.

Thank you

**EDIT**

Is there any extension with this feature? or could we get IP address of customer when they create an account?

I have found a way to change the customer's website by editing in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php

as follows

```
 `$this->_setFieldset($customer->getAttributes(), $fieldset);

    if ($customer->getId()) {
        $form->getElement('website_id'); // ->setDisabled('disabled');
        $form->getElement('created_in')->setDisabled('disabled');
    } else {
        $fieldset->removeField('created_in');
    }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making customer accounts Global (thus shared across websites) is natively supported in magento.

Browse in admin to system->configuraion then on the left under Customer heading, select 'customer configuration'

The first option: 'Share Customer Accounts' is by default 'Per Website' - change it to global.